# How to deal with node.js server locked in a long loop

Tags: node.js, server

If because of a bug or a totally unexpected and unplanned event, a production Node.js server running an application gets stuck in an infinite or long running loop, what can be done?

Is there a tool (like nodemon or forever) that will kill and restart a node server if it gets stuck for more than a given number of seconds?

In most multithreading systems, there is (or can be setup) a system of watchdogs that will kill threads that are performing bad, like taking too long to complete handling a request.

In node this can be handled only out-of-process killing and restarting the whole server. Is there a tool that already does that?

Comment: Have you tried this [Threads Go Go](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo)

Comment: Thanks @Thennarasan, it looks like a solution if I need to do long time processing, but my problem is different, I don't want the server to hangup for unexpected long time processing, in general, so kill and restart if it's more than, say, 30 seconds at 100% cpu not executing callbacks.

Comment: You know you can [loop asynchronously](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.times), and as such not hold the main process? I don't see such a tool as something useful, because it would just push bad practice. Still curious of a legit usage for this thought.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase the question, because I'm not saying that i WANT to make a long (or infinite) loop on the main process, I'm saying that IF it happens for whatever reason, and can happen for a ton of reasons, leaving a production server stuck should not be an option.

Comment: I'm not willing to push bad strategies, simply want to restart a server that got stuck, also failing with an error is a bad practice and still basically every node server gets restarted when fails with an exception. Why not to have a way to restart it if it gets stuck.

Comment: Hello @SimoneGianni
Have you solved this issue?